# How to delete all configurable products with associated simple products from certain category programmatically in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How to delete all configurable products with associated simple products from  certain category programmatically in Magento2?

I found an old topic for Magento 1, but that’s not what I need.

I know how to remove the simple and configuration separately, but I don’t understand how to remove all the configuration products and the simples attached to them with certain category magento2

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create PHP file in the Magento root directory like "deleteproducts.php". And add the below code to file.

> **Note:** **Please take a backup before running this script.**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';   // use '../app/bootstrap.php' if your root dir is pub

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');
 
$categoryId = 23; // YOUR CATEGORY ID
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                             
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    if($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
        $_configChild = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds($product);
        foreach ($_configChild as $childId){
            //Delete child products
            $childProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($childId);
            echo 'Child simple deleted - '.$childProduct->getName()."<br>";
            $childProduct->delete();
        }
        //Delete Configurable product
        $configurableProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
        echo 'Configurable deleted - '.$configurableProduct->getName()."<br>";
        $configurableProduct->delete();
    }
}
```

> Then run the script in the browser like yourdomain.com/deleteproducts.php

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the original script from @Kishor Thummar to improve performance and to log information while the script is running. You have to put the script in your webroot which is `pub` if you configured your server properly.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '18000');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require '../app/bootstrap.php';  // use "app/bootstrap.php" if your root is not set to pub folder (it should be though!)

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);

$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test_debug.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info("Script started.");

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');

$categoryId = 3; // YOUR CATEGORY ID
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

// Set filter, so that only configurable products are collected (faster).
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));   

foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    $logger->info($product->getName());
    $_configChild = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds($product);
    foreach ($_configChild as $childId){
        //Delete child products
        $childProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($childId);   
        $childProduct->delete();
        $logger->info("Child simple deleted - '". $childProduct->getName());
    }

    //Delete Configurable product
    $configurableProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
    $configurableProduct->delete();
    $logger->info('Configurable deleted - '.$configurableProduct->getName());
}

$logger->info("Script finished.");
```

Now you can run the script and watch the logfile with `tail -f var/log/test_debug.log`

Comment: what is the use of else condition?

Comment: @RohanHapani, sorry, forgot to remove it. Thank you for the hint!